# CakePHP migration leads to making edit to act like add

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.2

I have BlocksController and Block model. In [cakephp-1.2](/questions/tagged/cakephp-1.2) I used edit action to edit my application's blocks and it worked fine.

After migration to 1.3 and 2.x I noticed that the edit action leads to saving an edited block as a new record.

In the cakePHP docs I read that in 1.3 the form's helper does not supply the id any more and so the model regarded the process as add.

To solve this issue, I tried to add a hidden field named id with a value of the id of the block is being edited as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Block', array('class' => 'nice custom'));?>
//The following line is required in cakephp 1.3+

<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('id', array('value' => $block['Block']['id']));?>
```

The described solution is working fine. **However** I need to know another way to do that without changing in the view. Does it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `echo $this->Form->input('id')` as both documentation and baked code suggest?

Comment: @mark I just realized that it may not be printed out as a hidden form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**

There are any number of ways to accomplish what you want.  The most ideal solution would be to add the id into the view, similar to how you mentioned.  But - there are as many options as you can think of.

---

**In View**

The easiest (and I would argue the ideal) solution would just be to add the id in your view.  You should be able to just add it like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id');
```

It makes it hidden automatically since it's "id" and it should populate for you as well if you're passing the data correctly to the view.

---

**In Controller**

BUT - since your question was how to do it NOT in the view, another option is to do it in the Controller.  I don't know your exact project, so change it as you see fit, but before your save, you can always just append the Block's `id` to the data.

```
$this->request->data['Block']['id'] = $YOUR_ID;
$this->Block->save($this->request->data);
```

---

**In Model**

This seems like a strange place, but - you if you're storing the ID in session or something, you COULD theoretically add the id here before saving as well.